# How to concatenate/merge two sounds to play simultaneously in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio

I am required to make a song in MATLAB that features sampled noises and tones playing simultaneously, from research and what I was given it looked like it should be as simple as summing the two sounds, however I have been unable to figure it out. This is the code I've tried, I am new to coding so it may be inefficient. The length of 'snare' and 'A' are equal, both 1025.

```
load splat; y_splat = y;
Fs = 8192;             % the sampling rate
t = 0:1/Fs:0.125;      % an array of t values equally spaced from 0 to 0.125
f1 = 220;
A = sin(2*pi*f1*t);
snare = y_splat(7400:8424);

A_new = A + snare;
soundsc(A_new)
```

This code results in an error message: Only one- and two-channel audio supported.
What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a case of mismatch in dimensions. Though you may get an answer what I would recommend is that you contact your tutor. I would encourage you to engage with the staff at your institute way before asking a question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You have a dimension mismatch, `snare` is 1025x1 and `A` is 1x1025. Solve it by transpose one of them e.g
`A_new = A + snare';`

Answer (score 0):

I realised shortly after posting that the dimensions were mismatched. A simple apostrophe fixed the issue. Thank you for your responses.